# How can I get the exact training examples used in a batch in a callback?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm having a problem training a neural network in Keras. Every epoch, the loss will decrease steadily, reaching about 1e-9, then somewhere in the middle of the epoch (could be anywhere), the loss jumps up to 5e-5 and eventually just stabilizes at the same final loss each epoch. I believe this is due to some dirty data in my dataset causing the model to fail to train beyond a certain point, though I'm really not sure.

To test my hypothesis, I wanted to create a custom Keras callback object, that would determine if there's a big enough jump in the loss after a batch, and indicate which batch caused the jump. The problem is that the `batch` argument supplied to `keras.callbacks.Callback.on_batch_end` is just the batch *number*, and not actually the training examples *used* in that batch. Furthermore, the `logs` dict passed in as well only contains `loss` and `acc`.

This means I can't actually determine which pieces of data are causing the jump in the loss. Is there a way I can determine the exact training example that is causing the jump in each epoch? Is there some way I could access it in a callback?

Comment: Is it possible to get the training samples from the batch number or is the input unordered

Comment: @Primusa In some circumstances it might be possible, but only if the `shuffled` keyword argument supplied to `model.fit` is `False`, which it might not be.